# HTML code for drop downs is being rendered differently windows 7 and windows 10

Tags: html, dom, selenium-webdriver

For one of the applications I am working on I observe that HTML code for drop downs is different in Windows 7 and Windows 10.
WIndows 7 we see div tags for the dropdown whereas in Windows 10 we see select method.

We have osberved this issue consistently across different browsers.

Can someone please guide me on solution for selenium scripts to run on both the browsers without much change in such a situation?

Comment: Can you share the relevant _HTML_ of both the cases along with your code trials?

Comment: I would not be able to share the code, due to confidentiality.

Comment: Alright...then just check it out with the developers on this issue. they may give u a solution. If no other go then you can get the Operating System name and implement it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Either Specify all properties that are being changed across browsers, or make it so that the server/html gives different results across versions. Or use [conditional comments for IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx), which relates to the previous option (but is not server-side)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is wired. Haven't seen such issues. Just in case if you don't find a good solution then you can always do this :p

**This is just a work-around using Java**.

```
    if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Windows 10")) {
        // implement using select method
    }else {
        //implement using Div tags
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be tough to validate your observation without any sample of the relevant [*HTML DOM*](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) to analyze why *on WIndows7* you see *div* tags for the dropdown whereas in *Windows10* you see *select* tag.

However it's worth to mention the following points :

- Some of the relatively older websites have gone through reconstruction process and have decided to shift the workflow relating to *dropdown* functionality to be based on new `<li>` tags instead of previously active `<select>` tag. But the code for `<select>` tag remains. Hence the `<select>` tag related code remains as dead code.
- Some of the relatively older websites have gone through reconstruction process and have decided to shift the workflow relating to *dropdown* functionality to be based on both, the previously active `<select>` tag and newly introduced `<li>` tags. So both the code for `<select>` tag and `<li>` tags are into play.
- Some new websites have been reconstructed where the workflow relating to *dropdown* functionality is based on the combination of `<select>` tag and `<li>` tags. So both the code for `<select>` tag and `<li>` tags are into play.

A closer observation into the [*DOM Tree*](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) may solve our queries.

Here is a snapshot of an website which have `<select>` tag and `<li>` tag both but from *Selenium* perspective to interact with the *DropDown* identifying only the `<li>` will solve our purpose.

[image: dropdown_as_li_a]